# Aws S3 'vcf' files not downloading?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, vcf-vcard

I generate .vcf files in python.

*Production is in Linux*

*Testing is in Windows 7*

I push them to AWS s3 with `content-type` set as `text/x-vCard`.

The file gets there. https://s3.amazonaws.com/changeaddress/mms_storage/fb2489a59cf7442b971ad53cc104c49c_7c16e0f32d2e46d1bdfb928153168ad6.vcf But when clicked gives a blank page.

When I set the `content-type` to `text/plain` I do see the content of the vcard.  However, when I try to `save as` it won't download.   If I copy and paste the text into sublime and save as .vcf then it works.

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:;Budget Bicycle Center
FN:Budget Bicycle Center 
ORG:Budget Bicycle Center 
TEL;WORK;VOICE;PREF:+16082514232
ADR;WORK:;1201 Regent St;Madison;WI;53715;318112855E434DF793AD7F883A12DA9D
UID:318112855E434DF793AD7F883A12DA9D
REV:20150307172446686553
END:VCARD
```

I've tried to set Content-Disposition to attachment but that didn't seem to work either.

I'm out of ideas -- any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - So it was my chrome browser.

There is a very small glitch where if you have too many starting tabs open that it can funk up your browsers ability to download files.

Everything always worked above just need to restart chrome. Yikes.